# Question to any embedded systems engineers out there using STM32 NUCLEO

Tags: arm, stm32, nucleo

I have recently bought an STM32 NUCLEO Dev Kit and wondered if this what an actual Embedded Systems Engineer would use in the industry when developing a product?

I'm using Kiel Uvision 5, STMCubeMX and STM32 ST-LINK Utility to develop certain projects. As I am used to using PIC and using registers like PORTA, OSCCON, TIMER0 etc, I see that Kiel Uvision 5 uses ready made functions like HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(.........) etc. Is this the usual way they do this in industry or work more directly with the registers?

Comment: developers choice, you can develop at, and there are real developers that operate all all the various levels from roll your own, to rtos and libraries in between.  As a professional you are responsible for your part of the product.  If most of your code is third party your boss/company wont care that bugs in code that is within your realm of responsibility was not checked/validated by you.  if you spend a few seconds looking at some of these libraries you will start to get the picture I am presenting.

Comment: most folks will just use the libraries out of blind faith or being lazy or somewhere in between.  but that doesnt mean everyone does it.  you have to choose your path.  you can use testing to cover the code you didnt write or direct to have written.  I highly recommend for any of these platforms you try each of the available approaches and find the one that fits that product, schedule, cost, risk, etc.  and dont stick with that approach for life, as a professional you need to be able to develop under any of the options.

Comment: mcu vendors will typically have at least two library sets one is the new fangled new marketing ghee whiz the other being the older, reliable, tired, being phased out.  many reasons not just marketing and sales.   arm based chips are currently being affected by ARM itself in an interesting way making a third approach, and then there are the ported rtoses that may sit on any of the above.  so not just for arm but for other products these are typical choices and you need to choose.  when you get the first job this will generally be dictated and not your choice. for many years.

Answer (score 5):

It's heavily opinion based and I wouldn't get surprised if this question got closed for this reason. This answer only touches on few aspects of what you're asking about. It's a very broad topic and it's going to be hard - if not impossible - to include everything in one post which wouldn't end up being several pages long. However to give you my perspective on the topic, while trying to remain unbiased, the short answer is.. it depends.

If you're asking about what is used in most common cases, it's likely going to be the HAL (previously StdPeriph) functions you've mentioned. The reason is - they get the job done in most common cases. After all it always comes down to what the cost of creating a product is going to be. If HAL functions are "good enough" for the purpose, they're going to be used simply because they're faster to develop with. The higher the development cost, the more you'll want to cut it (or move it elsewhere) and using abstractions is one way of doing so.

However, even though I think it's safe to assume that HAL / Std Periph / any other (including proprietary) abstraction layer is generally used, it's not *always* the case for at least two reasons I can think of:

- Existing functions may not be suitable for your purpose. Giving HAL as an example, it works pretty well for most common cases, but sometimes your needs may be so specific that you'll have to go and mess "under the hood", often ending up either writing your own variation of the functions of building something new on top of HAL. Personally I can think of at least few examples where HAL functions weren't exactly what I needed. It doesn't necessarily mean that the library is bad, it's just sometimes the requirements are very specific.
- Messing with registers directly may sometimes be required for performance reasons.  HAL and similar are an abstraction layer and as any abstraction, they take more time to execute than using the registers directly. If you're trying to squeeze absolute maximum out of given peripheral, you'll sometimes have to go down to register level.

Now to a more biased portion of my answer.. I can see why you ask this question. Coming from PIC world where Flash or CPU clocks were more precious, it does make sense to use registers directly there. In case of STM32, it's not as critical anymore. Having said that, you'll sometimes stumble upon opinions that "using registers is the only true way", but personally I find such discussions ending up being purely academic. I see registers or any abstraction built on top of it as tools and you should use the right tools for the right job. Two examples of *NOT* using the right tools:

- You use only registers as "the only right way" either because you believe it yourself or you've been told so. Your products take twice (if not more) time to develop, your code takes less space in flash (so now you use 46% of 1MB flash instead of 48%). Code that is performance-critical meets its goals. Code that has relaxed execution time constraints is also super efficient, but it doesn't affect the end customer much, if at all. Your code is also less reusable - you find yourself rewriting same portions of code over and over every time you release new product for a new MCU family.
- You only use HAL / any other similar abstraction because "you didn't pick so powerful MCU to have to go down to register level", or because you're told you should never ever touch registers. You develop much faster and you're able to release two products instead of just one using registers. However when there are execution time constraints / transmission speeds you have to hit, you find yourself picking MCUs more powerful than should theoretically be needed. Sometimes you find yourself writing wrappers around HAL because they don't give you exactly the functionality you need - it feels like making it more complicated than it should be.

So after all, if there was anything to take out of what I'm trying to say is that you should use what is suitable for the job on a case-by-case basis. In case of STM32, you nowadays have 3 options: HAL (top abstraction level), HAL LL (Low Level abstraction - often simple wrapper functions around register acceses) or using registers directly. Which one you choose should come from what your requirements are.

Answer (score 1):

I use Nucleo boards all the time. It allows me to start write software before I have the actual hardware ready.

HAL & register way is rather the programmer choice than the "industry standard". I personally use HAL drivers when program more complicated peripherals like USB and Ethernet to avoid wiring the full stacks from the scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I have just finished my degree and we heavily used the STM32 platform with CMSIS and HAL.

It is a matter of preference. The HAL libraries offer higher abstraction but come with some quirks that are not very intuitive. The HAL (was/)is buggy sometimes. We have encountered SPI transfer bugs which made the higher transfer rates of SPI unusable because of a delay in the per byte transfer.

CMSIS offers lower level access but still abstracts away from simple bit manipulation. I don't think that direct register access is a great way to program anymore and at least CMSIS should be used. But it still a matter of opinion, preference and what is right for the job at hand. If you need something quick: HAL. If you need really fine control: CMSIS.

(sidenote I believe that CMSIS has been phased out in favor of HAL but it is still usable at this time)

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers are valid.
Just wanted to chime in and say I used STM32 regularly at my job (and at two different companies). We used the HAL drivers at both companies. There are obviously some issues with them, but used regularly enough by others that you can easily find support online. Additionally CubeMx does a decent job with them, at least enough to get you started on using the peripherals. So the 0->something step feel smaller. But getting really optimized code and design, you may want to dive deeper to really understand what each of the HAL drivers are doing and decide which method works for your project, goals, and requirements.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the answer because it will resolve someone else problem ASAP